# TreeSet not Adding Last Elements

Tags: java, integer, treeset

On two projects now, I haven't been able to add any integer of 0 or 1 to a `TreeSet<Integer>` in some conditions. I was able to work around it on the first one, but I do need every element in the array I'm taking numbers from to enter the TreeSet this time. Test code below.

```
int[] arr = {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0};
java.util.TreeSet<Integer> set = new java.util.TreeSet<Integer>();
for(int i: arr)
    set.add(arr[i]);
System.out.println(set);
```

If I put the 0 and 1 at the front of the list, it works perfectly. But I do need every element in that TreeSet under any circumstance, not just some, because in the actual project, I need to generate a bunch of random numbers and sort them in various ways.

Comment: Interesting! —„*…in some conditions…*“ — It might be useful say something about what those conditions are; at least *some* of them. — „*…I was able to work around it…*“ — Was the work-around putting the 0 and 1 at the front of the list? TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how you print a TreeSet in java.

This is what you should be using:

```
for(Integer number : set){
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

Directly printing out Lists, Arrays, Sets or any sort of collection will always give you an unusable result.

Furthermore, you aren't properly adding items to the TreeSet. It should be:

```
for(int i: arr){
    set.add(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're adding arr[i] to your set, instead of adding i.

Answer (score 1):

you can take this one i do Treeset with ArrayList instead of Array you can add elements
It work fine :)

```
package stackoverflowtest;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        List<String> sets= new ArrayList<>();
        
        sets.add("10");
        sets.add("9");
        sets.add("8");
        sets.add("7");    
        sets.add("6");
        sets.add("4");
        sets.add("3");
        sets.add("3");
        sets.add("3");
        sets.add("2");
        sets.add("2");
        sets.add("2");
        sets.add("1");
        sets.add("0");
        
        TreeSet<String> set = new TreeSet<>();
        set.addAll(sets);
        
        System.out.println(set);        
        System.out.println(set.descendingSet());
        
        System.out.println(set.first());
        System.out.println(set.last());
        
           
    }
}
```

Your output

```
[0, 1, 10, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[9, 8, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2, 10, 1, 0]
0
9
```